# Галерея в RecyclerView. Проблема с масштабированием

Tags: android, recyclerview, vector-drawable

Есть диалог выбора аватарки.
При первом запуске имею это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее, прокручиваю на 1 ряд ниже. Имею:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возвращаюсь на 1 ряд вверх (обратно):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть проблема в том, что первые отображаемые картинки почему-то меньше чем любые картинки, которые станут видимы после скролла. Как с этим справиться?..

Адаптер

```
public class AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AvaChooseRecyclerAdapter.AvaViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "AvaChooseAdapter";

List<Integer> resourceIds = Arrays.asList(
        R.drawable.avatars_01, R.drawable.avatars_02, R.drawable.avatars_03,
        R.drawable.avatars_04, R.drawable.avatars_05, R.drawable.avatars_06,
        R.drawable.avatars_07, R.drawable.avatars_08, R.drawable.avatars_09,
        R.drawable.avatars_10, R.drawable.avatars_11, R.drawable.avatars_12,
        R.drawable.avatars_13, R.drawable.avatars_14, R.drawable.avatars_15,
        R.drawable.avatars_16, R.drawable.avatars_17, R.drawable.avatars_18,
        R.drawable.avatars_19, R.drawable.avatars_20, R.drawable.avatars_21,
        R.drawable.avatars_22, R.drawable.avatars_23, R.drawable.avatars_24,
        R.drawable.avatars_25, R.drawable.avatars_26, R.drawable.avatars_27,
        R.drawable.avatars_28, R.drawable.avatars_29, R.drawable.avatars_30,
        R.drawable.avatars_31, R.drawable.avatars_32, R.drawable.avatars_33,
        R.drawable.avatars_34, R.drawable.avatars_35, R.drawable.avatars_36,
        R.drawable.avatars_37, R.drawable.avatars_38, R.drawable.avatars_39,
        R.drawable.avatars_40, R.drawable.avatars_41, R.drawable.avatars_42,
        R.drawable.avatars_43, R.drawable.avatars_44, R.drawable.avatars_45,
        R.drawable.avatars_46, R.drawable.avatars_47, R.drawable.avatars_48,
        R.drawable.avatars_49, R.drawable.avatars_50, R.drawable.avatars_51,
        R.drawable.avatars_52, R.drawable.avatars_53, R.drawable.avatars_54,
        R.drawable.avatars_55, R.drawable.avatars_56, R.drawable.avatars_57,
        R.drawable.avatars_58, R.drawable.avatars_59, R.drawable.avatars_60,
        R.drawable.avatars_61, R.drawable.avatars_62, R.drawable.avatars_63,
        R.drawable.avatars_64, R.drawable.avatars_65, R.drawable.avatars_66);


public static class AvaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView iv;

    public AvaViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ava_item_imageview);
    }
}


@Override
public AvaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ava_item, parent, false);
    v.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    return new AvaViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AvaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder position: " + position + " | holder obj:" + holder.toString());
    holder.iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    holder.iv.setImageResource(resourceIds.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return resourceIds.size();
}
```

Разметка

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ava_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ava_item_imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите код адаптера, желательно место где вы устанавливаете размер картинок или вью

Comment: И хмл (R.id.ava_item_imageview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить одинаковый размер VectorDrawable максимальным при использовании в RecyclerView с вертикальной прокруткой, необходимо у корневого элемента установить:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Я полагаю, для горизонтальной прокрутки параметры надо поменять на противоположные.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что вы используете 
`android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
Попробуйте установить точный размер в DP, например 40dp высота и ширина. Это должно решить проблему, если вам надо варьировать размер в зависимости от экрана, то рассчитывайте перед созданием адаптера размер и устанавливайте его программно для изображений

Пример

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ava_item"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ava_item_imageview"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: а как рассчитать размер перед созданием адаптера?

Comment: @EvgenyGooDi например можно получить размеры экрана (ширину), от этого размера например взять 1/4 и устанавливать его вью

Comment: где в коде правильно это сделать? пробую в коде активити до присвоения адаптера списку. но не пойму как передать вычисленное значение в адаптер для установки размера...

Comment: например через setIconsSize(int) у адаптера сделать и сетить до установки адаптера на лист